# How to get the hovered div position

Tags: css, angular, tooltip

I want my tooltip to be aligned next to the hovered element. How can I find the position of hovered element such that it works in devices also. I am passing the hovered element event on mouseenter.

I tried setting the ClientX, ClientY or screenX, ScreenY position to top and left but it's not working properly.

[image: tooltip misalignment]

Answer (score 0):

## Example

As you dont provided any code source I created a sample to show what you can do:

```js
var ul = document.querySelector('ul');
var li = ul.querySelectorAll('li');
var tooltip = document.querySelector('.tooltip');
var removeTooltip;

function onMouseOver(e) {
  return function() {
    clearTimeout(removeTooltip);
    
    tooltip.innerHTML = e.innerHTML;
   
    var w = window;
    var tooltipTopPosition = e.offsetTop + (e.clientHeight / 2) - (tooltip.clientHeight / 2);
    var leftPosition = e.offsetLeft + e.offsetWidth + 5;
    var toolTipWidth = w.innerWidth - leftPosition - 5;
    
    tooltip.style.top = tooltipTopPosition + 'px';
    tooltip.style.left = leftPosition + 'px';
    tooltip.style.width = toolTipWidth + 'px';
  }
}

function onMouseLeave(e) {
  return function() {
    clearTimeout(removeTooltip);
    
    removeTooltip = setTimeout(function() {
      tooltip.innerHTML = '';  
    }, 100);
    
  };
}

li.forEach(function(item) {
  item.onmouseover = onMouseOver(item);
  item.onmouseleave = onMouseLeave(item);
});
```

```css
.tooltip {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: normal;
}

ul {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px dotted;
}
```

```html
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem.</li>
    <li>Necessitatibus.</li>
    <li>Dolorum.</li>
    <li>Est.</li>
  </ul>
  
  <div class="tooltip"></div>
```